# apt-get install reading package list... error

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, apt-get

so I'm trying to install heroku toolbelt with

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

but, I get this error:

```
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/non-free Translation-en_US             
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/non-free Translation-en
Fetched 910 B in 14s (63 B/s)
Reading package lists... Error!
```

W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and     the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The   following signatures were invalid: BADSIG A040830F7FAC5991 Google, Inc. Linux Package   Signing Key

so I tried to use sudo apt-get install, and I get the same exact error. How do I fix this and install heroku toolbelt?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! However, questions on this site should relate to computer programming. Please consider editing this question to make it more relavent, or migrating it.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to downloading it from a repository is to install the standalone version

```
    wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```